# Do I have to connect to a local Database to use it's table values? How do I access the table values?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, linq

In Visual Studio C#, I am creating a cashier sales system and want to have a database to store the values of the sales, products etc instead of creating an array to store the pre-defined values inside a class.
I have created a Local Database C# item and created a table with values inside but when I want to access those values I do not know how.

I've searched the internet(where I found out about the database item) and it leads me to having to connect to the database first. Is this necessary? and If so how do you connect to it?

I've done this below but when I run my program nothing appears

```
SqlConnection x = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;"+ "Database=Database1;");

x.Open();
```

Thank you very much,
Student_SS

P.S Forgive me if this is actually a basic question, my teacher has not taught this but I am required to do it for a project.

Comment: The answer is yes. I think at this point you should find a simple database tutorial or walk-through. Also a teachers job is to teach, dont be afraid to ask questions

Comment: Opening a connection to your database system is just the first step, now you should read the information stored in the _database tables_ and load your _in memory objects_. Then you update your objects and finally store them in the database. You have just begun your journey, you need a [good tutorial on ADO.NET](https://www.bing.com/search?q=ado.net%20tutorial&qs=AS&sk=AS1&pq=ADO.NET&sp=2&sc=8-7&form=BDKTKA&pc=BDT1&shash=&BDParam=0000&mkt=en-US)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are some of the link for crud operation in asp.net C# with sql database.

https://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/make-edit-update-and-delete-operation-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4aae29/complete-crud-operations-in-Asp-Net/

learn how to connect database and retrieve data from database and bind it your page.

Comment: Link only questions are fairly low quality

Comment: @TheGeneral asking a question like "how to connect to a sql database" is a fairly low quality question as well. If the OP can't do some googling for this basic question there is nothing wrong in posting links since this question was asked and answered a MILLION times.

Comment: @TheGeneral yes you are write link only is low quality. that's why I have mentioned about the link that for which purpose I have posted the links. I can't explain much about the content of the link or I can't explain questioner about the connection and sqlcommand so I thought its better for him to learn from the links :)